# Problem with arc length

Tags: functions

```
length[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Module[{m, n}, 
  m = N[Integrate[Sqrt[
     1 + (D[b[t], t])^2/(D[a[t], t])^2], {x, c, d}]]; 
  n = Sqrt[(a[d] - a[c])^2 + (b[d] - b[c])^2]; 
  Print["Arc Length = ", m]; Print["Closest length = ", n];
  ]
```

will it work ?

I'm sorry i am still learning wolfram's language.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use it?

Comment: yes, it wont work

Comment: That is the answer, isn't it? :) But jokes aside, what about replacing `x` with `t` and showing us examples for which it fails?